# Inconsistent warning emission in data.table with 'by' argument?

Tags: r, data.table

I will produce a new data.table column by reference with `by` argument. If the group results have different data types (here `int` and `num`) they will be coerced to the same one (here `num` to `int`) depending on the order of groups data types. The first example produces no warning but the second does. Why?

R version 4.0.4

data.table version 1.14.8

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a = c("rpois", "rnorm"))

DT[, b := ifelse(a == "rpois", 1L, 1.0), by = "a"]

set.seed(6)
DT[, c := match.fun(a)(1, 1), by = "a"]

str(DT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the warning:

```
set.seed(6)
DT[, c := match.fun(a)(1, 1), by = "a"]
# Warning message:
# In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(b, ifelse(a == "rpois", 1L, 1.2)),  :
#   Group 2 column 'b': 1.200000 (type 'double') at RHS position 1 # truncated (precision lost) when assigning to type 'integer'
```

It is warning you about "precision lost". No precision is lost when `1.0` is converted to `1` because they are mathematically equal. If your first example did have loss in precision, you would get the same warning:

```
DT[, b := ifelse(a == "rpois", 1L, 1.2), by = "a"]
# Warning message:
# In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(b, ifelse(a == "rpois", 1L, 1.2)),  :
#   Group 2 column 'b': 1.200000 (type 'double') at RHS position 1 truncated # (precision lost) when assigning to type 'integer'
```